# How to change a live Laravel site?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to work on a Laravel site someone made but I've never worked with Larvel. I've done some research and as far as I gather it works on a MVC system.
We have our own servers/domain and I need to make some changes to the site.

How can I access the Views/Models of the site?

Do i need to make the changes with Larvel

edit: I've found the views under a storage folder but the naming for the folders seems to be randomized letters/numbers.
Can I edit from here?

edit 2: Do I need to run Laravel to make changes or can i edit the Views directly without it actually breaking the site?

Comment: Views are in `resources`, models and controllers are in `app`. Though this question is far too broad for this platform - I suggest you pick up a Laravel tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel actually has [a very well written documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8). I suggest you go through this before trying to edit the first things you encounter.

The storage folder should never be edited manually, this is where the application stores data. The view folder you found contains compiled views and will be overwritten when loading the application. The actual views are located in `resources/views`.

All application logic can be found under the `app/` folder. In here, logic should be separated by domain.

To develop a Laravel application, you don't really need any particular application. Any editor will do.
Of course, I would recommend to install PHP on your machine so you can debug the application locally.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, The actual views are located in resources/views. You may change the views as per the requiment. Check this link [Views - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views)

You can refer the documentation provided by the the Laravel. Here is the link for laravel-basic [Laravel Basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

Try to ask the specific question or the thing which you don't know.